# 1 Button + Potentiometer

Tags: arduino-uno, c

Sketch
arduino-uno programming
1 Button and 1 Potentiometer

Sketch: Each time the button is pressed, acquire the value of the potentiometer in a array of 10 positions of these values do the average and print it on the serial monitor or display.

At the end print the average (sum of values ​​/ 10)

```
#define BUTTON 5
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10
int counter = 0;
int valori[ARRAY_SIZE];
int pinPotenziometro = A0;
int statoPresenteBottone = LOW; //why so LOW?
float media = 0.0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
  for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) valori[i] = 0;
}
void loop() {
  if (counter > ARRAY_SIZE) {
    counter = 00;
    media = 0.0; // when we fill array fully - we start again
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) valori[i] = 0;
  }
  statoPresenteBottone = digitalRead (BUTTON);
  while (statoPresenteBottone == HIGH) {
    valori[counter] = analogRead(A0);
    media = media + valori[counter];
   Serial.print("Average: ");
   Serial.println(media / counter);
   Serial.print("Button pressed times: ");
   Serial.println(counter);
    statoPresenteBottone = LOW;
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Can u guys edit the Sketch? Cuz if u try It on tinkercad with adding a potentiometer+ a button u will see he does the average after each value we acquired but i need to do that at the end...
I dont need explaining of how i should i do It cuz the teacher did that already but these are my skills D: if u guys can edit the sketch and solve this problem would be cool thx

Comment: Duplicate of the OPs previous question: [Schematic: 1 Button and 1 Potentiometer Sketch](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/84401/schematic-1-button-and-1-potentiometer-sketch)

Comment: So your teacher explained to you, how you should solve the problem? And now you are asking as to do the rest of your homework for you? And you ask us to build the project ourselves in tinkercad? Sorry, we are not here to do other peoples homework. We are not a free code writing/editing service. And when you are talking about a tinkercad simulation, you should provide a link to a public tinkercad project, that you build. I don't have an account there and I also don't want to build up the project from your description. Please provide such things in your question, if you want good answers.

Comment: basically there is AN array of 10 positions every time we press the Button he acquires the value of the potentiometer (we do that for 10 times) at the end he does the sum of values/array_size and print the average , the link of public project Is : https://www.tinkercad.com/things/cNjZS9Oz02j-progetto-media-varianza-da-finire-d-uwu-uwu-uwu-lt3/editel?sharecode=Bs8_pG7HsyANlYI4yp9W2cuaJ20dIlfdgQmPhO1U1zY

Comment: You didn't actually answer to the other things that I wrote. Though your tinkercad project doesn't seem to be public. I cannot see it without login in.

Comment: ah 1 sec i will update link

Comment: Please put that link in your original question. This one will be closed soon, since it is basically the same question, as before.

Comment: Ok but its public already the link y can edit